# How to create custom editor with model binding using tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have used following code in multiple views:

```
<input asp-for="@Model.Tags" class="form-control" data-provider="tagseditor" />
<!-- some additional code will be added in future -->
```

and I would like to take this code and create reusable TagHelper (or alternativelly ViewComponent) from it so I will use it like this:

```
<tags-editor for="@Model.Tags" />
```

However I'm not able to pass the `ModelExpression` from my custom tag helper into underlying InputTagHelper.

I'm getting:

> ArgumentException: The name of an HTML field cannot be null or empty. Instead use methods
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper.Editor or
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.IHtmlHelper`1.EditorFor with a
>   non-empty htmlFieldName argument value. Parameter name: expression

On this this line: `_htmlHelper.PartialAsync`

```
<!-- Views/Shared/TagHelpers/TagsEditor -->
@model ModelExpression
<input asp-for="@Model" class="form-control" data-provider="tagseditor" />
```

```
[HtmlTargetElement("tags-editor", Attributes = "for", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
public class TagsEditorTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private HtmlHelper _htmlHelper;
    private HtmlEncoder _htmlEncoder;

    public TagsEditorTagHelper(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, HtmlEncoder htmlEncoder)
    {
        _htmlHelper = htmlHelper as HtmlHelper;
        _htmlEncoder = htmlEncoder;
    }


    [HtmlAttributeName("for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext
    {
        set => _htmlHelper.Contextualize(value);
    }


    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = null;

        //exception thrown here:
        var partial = await _htmlHelper.PartialAsync("TagHelpers/TagsEditor", For);

        var writer = new StringWriter();
        partial.WriteTo(writer, _htmlEncoder);

        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(writer.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very clever use of partial views.

Answer (score 1):

The gist of the problem comes from the fact that the `ModelExpression` is not a model in itself. You'll have to call its `Model` property.

So in your partial view:

```
<!-- Views/Shared/TagHelpers/TagsEditor -->
@model ModelExpression
<input asp-for="@Model.Model" class="form-control" data-provider="tagseditor" />
```

Then, you can't set the output tag name to null, because that will generate a `<null></null>` tag in your view. I suggest you change it to "div", or whatever container works for you.

Finally, because the input tag is self closing, you'll need to change the output tag mode to `TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag` to force generating `<div></div>` instead of just `<div/>`.

All told, the `ProcessAsync` method becomes:

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    output.TagName = "div";
    output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;

    var partial = await _htmlHelper.PartialAsync("TagHelpers/TagsEditor", For);
    var writer = new StringWriter();
    partial.WriteTo(writer, _htmlEncoder);

    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(writer.ToString());
}
```